# How do I extract these values from an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help, I have an Angular method that I'm trying to get the values out of an object and get a result looks "**Monday-Friday: 0800-1600**"

```
$scope.ourHours = {
  services: [{
    title: "Office hours",
    phone: "1-800-123-1234",
    hours: [
      {day:'Monday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Tuesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Wednesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Thursday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Friday',open:'0800',close:'1800'}
    ]
  }]
};
```

Comment: So what if your data is different, and you have different open/close times per day, or missing days, ... this question needs clarification.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: If the repetition of the data is certain then just write it down the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep track of the previous days, and if the hours match, group them:

```js
function getHoursText(hours){
    var arr = [], txt = [];

    for(var i=0; i<hours.length; i++){
        if(arr.length &&
           (arr[0].open !== hours[i].open || arr[0].close !== hours[i].close)
          ){
            txt.push(arrayToText(arr));
            arr = [];
        }
        arr.push(hours[i]);
    }

    txt.push(arrayToText(arr));

    return txt.join('\n');

    function arrayToText(arr){
        var str;
        if(!arr.length){ return ""; }
        str = arr[0].day;
        if(arr.length > 1){ str += '-' + arr.pop().day; }
        str += ': ' + arr[0].open + '-' + arr[0].close;
        return str;
    }
}

/*
 * Example usage
 */
var hours = [
      {day:'Monday',open:'0800',close:'1500'},
      {day:'Tuesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Wednesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Thursday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
      {day:'Friday',open:'0800',close:'1500'}
    ];

console.log( getHoursText(hours) );
```

Comment: Thanks in advance @blex I will try your method tonight

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('hours', function() {
  return function(item) {
    return item.substr(0,2) + ":" + item.substr(2,2);
  }
})
.controller('ShopHours', function ShopHours($scope) {
  $scope.ourHours = {
    services: [{
      title: "Office hours",
      phone: "1-800-123-1234",
      hours: [
        {day:'Monday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
        {day:'Tuesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
        {day:'Wednesday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
        {day:'Thursday',open:'0800',close:'1800'},
        {day:'Friday',open:'0800',close:'1800'}
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ShopHours">
  <div ng-repeat="serv in ourHours.services">
    <h3>{{serv.title}}</h3>
    <p>Phone: {{serv.phone}}</p>
    <div>Hours:
      <ng-repeat ng-repeat="hours in serv.hours">
        <p><b>{{hours.day}}:</b> from {{hours.open | hours}} to {{hours.close | hours}}</p>
      </ng-repeat>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```